# selenium checkbox click not working in python

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox, css-selectors, webdriverwait

https://agent.loadbook.in/#/login
When I go to the signup form, the form has a checkbox as I agree with the condition. It's an Input tag checkbox. when I select the tag by id and when I perform click or send_key of submitting its showing checkbox not clickable.

below all Method are not work

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="switch__container"]//input').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="switch__container"]//input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="switch__container"]//input').submit()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="switch__container"]//input').send_keys("after")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="switch__container"]//label').click()



driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://agent.loadbook.in/#/login")


driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Create an account").click()
```

try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="switch__container"]//input').click()
# driver.find_element("name","username").send_keys("test")
# driver.find_element("name","email").send_keys("test@test.com")
# driver.find_element("name","phone").send_keys("99999999")
# driver.find_element("name","password").send_keys("12345")
```

> except NoSuchElementException as exception:
>       print("not found")
>
> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
>   element not interactable

Comment: On sign up page its not check box actually its toggle

Answer (score 1):

You need to **wait** for the element to appear in DOM using Selenium's [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) feature.

1. Open the page using [WebDriver.get()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get) function

   ```
   driver.get("https://agent.loadbook.in/#/login")
   ```
2. [Click](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click) "Create an account" link:

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_link_text("Create an account").click()
   ```
3. [Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) until the checkbox loads and becomes clickable:

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "switch_div")))
   ```
4. Click the checkbox:

   ```
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("switch_div").click()
   ```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the checkbox asociated with text as **I agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  # options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://agent.loadbook.in/#/login")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Create an account"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='switch-shadow']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Iagree]